# IMAGE field in terminal output of docker history command shows <missing>

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand how docker build cache works. I ran `docker history <imageID>` command to see more information about each layer. But I noticed that `IMAGE` of intermediate layers are shown as .

Terminal output of build process
[image]

Terminal output of docker history command
[image]

Can somebody explain, what does  in `IMAGE` field mean?. Does it imply that layer is built during the image build process or taken from the cache without building.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-image-history-shows-missing-on-image-name/33948/2

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  You may need to [edit] your question to include the terminal output as plain text and not images.  As you've described the question it's not obviously about programming, and it may be more appropriate to ask on another site like [unix.se] or [devops].